# Laravel 5.2 Model.php Relationship method Exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have started learning Laravel 5.2, I am using this piece of code to save data

```
Route::get('hello', function () {

    $info = new info;
    $info->name = "Test";
    $info->save;

    return view('hello');
});
```

Data is stroing successfully, but at the same time I am getting an exception.

[image: Screenshot of the exception]

The table info is the only table inside DB and have nothing like relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling the function save. Correct it to:

```
$info->save();
```

It thinks it's a relation because that's how you reference model relations... (ie. without the brackets)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Sorry for this stupid mistake posted here.

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `$info = new info;`
you should use:   `$info = new info();`